# how to view line break in page source

Tags: html, newline, line-breaks

If I view page source of below html page:

```
This is first line text
This is second line text
```

I can see:

```
<div><font color="black">This is first line text<br>
This is second line text<br></font>
```

But if the above lines are in `<pre></pre>` tag, the page source is like something below:

```
This is first line text
This is second line text
```

i.e, I can't see any html tags like `<\n>` or `<nl2br>` here. Is there any browser plugin or php code so that I can view from page source, whether the new line/ line break within `<pre></pre>` tag is either `<\n>` or `<nl2br>` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use js(jQuery) to do this, please check this link, a small example, hope it helps =D

```
$("pre").each(function(index) {
  let pre_text = JSON.stringify($(this).text())
  alert(pre_text);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/hhsaukec/4/

then you can save those raw data into a hidden tag? or do whatever you want.

Comment: Thankyou very much. I actually expected this kind of function. I accepted your answer. One more thing, Is there any function that can show other html entity codes too, like it will show tab, indent, &amp; etc from the line? If there any function, I will open a new Question topic. Thanks again.